# Why do Vincent and Cole both have a patch of white hair on their head?

Tags: the-sixth-sense

In [*The Sixth Sense*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167404/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt), Vincent and Cole both have a patch of white in their hair.

> Cole and Vincent both have a patch of grey/white hair, both on the
>   right side of their heads. Vincent's is to the side and Cole's is
>   behind the ear.

Vincent's can be seen on the right side right above his ear.

[image: Vincent]

Cole's can be seen on the right side right behind his ear.

[image: Cole]

**Why do they both have this patch of white hair?  Why is it on the right side?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This seems to have been something intended by Shyamalan

[**EW.com**](http://ew.com/article/1999/09/10/success-sixth-sense/)

> Shyamalan wanted all spirit spotters to share a physical trait. **He figured a shock of white would result from the trauma of being a regular on spectral rotations.** That’s why Osment has it, as does the deranged patient who attacks Willis in the beginning.

Comment: "Spirit Spotters" - sounds like a wacky 1980's cartoon series.

Comment: just commenting to say this is such a stupid plot point. but what else would you expect from shyamalan? >_>

Comment: @sgroves It's not unheard of.  Spielberg did it with the mother's character in the original _Poltergeist_.

Comment: @user22792 i didn't say it was unheard of; i said it was stupid. :)